# Dialogflow CX - using sys.person gives wierd output

Tags: dialogflow-cx

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1bZD.png

I am using sys.person to capture the person's name. Is there any way for just 'john' and not the entire {"name": "john"} to show instead? I want to avoid sys.given-name and sys.last-name since dialogflow says they are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your entity configured as a list? If it is a list, you probably have to output the parameter like `$session.params.name[0].name`.

If it's not a list, `$session.params.name.name` would work, but in that case I suggest you change the entity name to `person`, as it would be more readable to see `$session.params.person.name`

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it looks like your parameter is an isList parameter.

I have checked today the behavior of static responses when referencing isList parameters and it seems that we can now display the list of values for a certain parameter without the array index in the responses using the format: [$session.params.parameter-id](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#session-ref).

In your case, it would be:
[$session.params.name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FIoD.png).

In addition, if you want to reference a specific array index in an isList parameter, you can use the format [$session.params.parameter-id[i]](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#session-ref). In your case, it would be [$session.params.name[0]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTvD7.png)

or if you want to get the original value you can reference it as [$session.params.name[0].original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q1so.png)